# Computing an Integral using Contour Integration $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{x^3 + 1} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

How does one compute the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{x^3 + 1} dx$, where $0 < \alpha < 1$, using contour integration?

Comment: You really need to show your work. In general you do the following: (1) "complexify" your function, (2) pick a contour that includes the real axis and hopefully has pieces that are easy to evaluate, (3) determine the poles inside the contour and their residues, (4) apply the Residue Theorem.

Comment: But what is a good contour?

Comment: A circular sector of angle $2\pi/3$. Or a keyhole contour.

Comment: Just a guess: you need to pick a principal branch for $z^a$, so I'd suggest defining $z^a$ in the usual way on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$, and picking a keyhole contour with the "corridor" above and below the real axis.

Answer (score 2):

Not a proof by contour integration strictly speaking, but a proof through something more versatile, also known as Herglotz' trick.

---

By enforcing the substitution $x=z^{2/3}$ the problem can be solved through the well-known identity

> $$ \forall \beta\in(-1,1),\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^\beta}{z^2+1}\,dz = \frac{\pi}{2\cos\frac{\pi\beta}{2}}\tag{WNI}$$

**Proof**: the integral equals $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^\beta+x^{-\beta}}{x^2+1}\,dx $ or
$$ F(\beta)=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\left[\frac{1}{(\beta+2n+1)}+\frac{1}{(-\beta+2n+1)}\right]=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n (4n+2)}{(2n+1)^2-\beta^2}$$
which is a meromorphic function with simple poles with residue $\pm 1$ at any odd integer. Since
$$\cos\frac{\pi\beta}{2}=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{\beta^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right) $$
the same holds for $\frac{\pi}{2\cos\frac{\pi\beta}{2}}$. Clearly $F(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and both $F(\beta)$ and $\frac{\pi}{2\cos\frac{\pi\beta}{2}}$ are log-convex functions over the interval $(-1,1)$; the latter by direct inspection, the former through the Cauchy-Schwarz/Holder inequality applied to $ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^\beta}{z^2+1}\,dz$. This finishes the proof.

---

By $(\text{WNI})$, for any $\alpha\in(-1,2)$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{x^3+1}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{3\cos\frac{\pi(2\alpha-1)}{3}}. $$

Answer (score 2):

Following Daniel Fischer's advice, namely to use a circular sector of angle $2\pi/3$ with radius $R>1$. The contour is shown below.

[image]

Before getting to work, the Logarithm that will be used is the Principal Logarithm. Okay, we integrate the following:
\begin{align}
\oint_C\frac{z^\alpha}{1+z^3}\,dz
\end{align}
The only pole inclosed is $z=e^{i\pi/3}$ so we get by the Residue Theorem:
\begin{align}
\oint_C\frac{z^\alpha}{1+z^3}\,dz&=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=e^{i\pi/3}}\frac{z^\alpha}{1+z^3}\\
&=2\pi i \frac{e^{i\pi/3}e^{i\alpha\pi/3}}{(e^{i2\pi/3}-e^{-i2\pi/3})(e^{i\pi/3}-e^{-i\pi/3})}\\
&=-i\pi \frac{e^{i\pi/3}e^{i\alpha\pi/3}}{2\sin(\pi/3)\sin(2\pi/3)} \\
&=-i\frac{2\pi}{3}e^{i\pi/3}e^{i\alpha\pi/3}
\end{align}
Moreover we have:
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\oint_C\frac{z^\alpha}{1+z^3}\,dz = (1-e^{i\alpha2\pi/3}e^{i2\pi/3})\int^R_0 \frac{t^\alpha}{t^3+1}\,dt + \int_{B_R}\frac{z^\alpha}{1+z^3}\,dz 
\end{align}
The last one is the integral on the circular part and that goes to zero as $R\to\infty$ hence:
\begin{align}
(1-e^{i\alpha2\pi/3}e^{i2\pi/3})\int^\infty_0 \frac{t^\alpha}{t^3+1}\,dt=-i\frac{2\pi}{3}e^{i\pi/3}e^{i\alpha\pi/3}
\end{align}
Hence:
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{t^\alpha}{t^3+1}\,dt&=-i\frac{2\pi}{3}\frac{e^{i\pi/3}e^{i\alpha\pi/3}}{1-e^{i\alpha2\pi/3}e^{i2\pi/3}}\\
\end{align}
Simplifying the last expression:

> $$\int^\infty_0 \frac{t^\alpha}{t^3+1}\,dt=\frac{\pi}{3\sin[(1+\alpha)\pi/3]}$$

**Remark.** This answer has almost full elaboration, but there are still things that must be verified, for example $(xy) ^\alpha=x^\alpha y^\alpha$ used in $(1)$ indirectly (does not hold in general).