# Calculate $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{x^3+1} dx$ using residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Although I've found similar integrals, I haven't found this.

Determine the values $a \geq 0 $ such that the integral:

$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{x^3+1}dx $ is convergent.

For these values calculate it.

I have managed to check that $ a \in  [0, 2) $, checking the interval $ (0, 1] $, in which there is no issues, because the limit tends to zero.

Also in $ [1, \infty) $, I get $$ \int_1^\infty x^{(a-3)} dx $$ and get that $ a < 2 $ or else it diverges because of the p-test.

Now to calculate by residue I'm unsure how to proceed, since it does not state that $ a $ is natural.

Comment: Searching with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E%5Cinfty%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ea%7D%7Bx%5E3%2B1%7Ddx%24&p=1) or [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7Ba%7D%7D%7Bx%5E3+%2B+1%7D+dx%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=) returns some posts which contain this integral, such as: [Computing an Integral using Contour Integration $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{x^3 + 1} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2590376).

Comment: There is also a questions about a more general problem: [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this searchers.

Comment: In case it helps, here is a proposed FAQ for searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the integral  $$\oint \frac{z^a}{z^3+1} \, dz = \oint \frac{\exp[a \log z]}{z^3+1} \, dz$$ over a suitable contour.

The contour could be a wedge from the origin to the real point $R$, then an arc of a circle to the point $\beta$ and back to the origin.

The point $\beta$ could be $R\exp[\frac{2 \pi i}{3}]$ containing one pole inside.  Other similarly constructed contours will also work.